# Best way to make a multiplayer turn-by-turn online game with python back end

Tags: python, django

As a project for a friend's birthday I am trying to create an online multiplayer game which is based on this derivative of poker we play. I only really know how to code python so started with that and have managed to create the game basics and I guess it could be a good back end for the game but don't know how to get it online or as an app so my friend could actually play it with me.

Is there a way to use python code as a back end for an online game? I've read about Django and other frameworks but can't seem to get my head around how that would actually work.

The UI for the game really doesn't matter too much as long as theres some way to take multiple user inputs.

Appreciate any help and apologies if I use any wrong terminology Im self taught for the most part

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Django to make your game a web app and play it with you friend. There are many tutorials online to do this; 
I suggest [this one](https://codyparker.com/django-channels-with-react/), it uses django and reactJS.

However, if his birthday is soon and you're in hurry, I don't recommend learning reactJS now (in case you're not already familiar with it). You can use simple django templates with html, css and javascript, wont take that much time. You can refer to [Django official documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/fr/2.1/) to learn the basics of Django and then pull it off yourself.

Good luck.